# How can I fill the corner of a page with a wave like drawing in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have made the following drawing using the original drawing on the tikzpgf manual's cover page ([link](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/title-graphics/)). But now I want to have one of those wave like shapes to be expanded in the corner of my page with fading colours.

I mean, I want a wave type drawing, fill a quarter of a circle and the colour of it fade when the distance to the centre increases. Also, I want to decrease the segments sizes when it comes so near to the edge of the circle.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twosided,openright]{book}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,snakes}


\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling angle=120]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling angle=60]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[sibling angle=30]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[fill]
\tikzstyle{edge from parent}=[snake=expanding waves,segment length=1mm,segment angle=10,draw]
\begin{tikzpicture}[shape=circle,very thick,level distance=13mm,cap=round]
\node {} child [color=\A] foreach \A in {red,green,blue}
    { node {} child [color=\A!50!\B] foreach \B in {red,green,blue}
        { node {} child [color=\A!50!\B!50!\C] foreach \C in {black,gray,white}
            { node {} }
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\wave{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \fill[red,line width=.5mm,draw=red] (current page.north west) circle (3mm);
    \def\max{20}
    \foreach \i in {4,...,\max} {
      \draw[red,line width=.5mm,draw opacity={(\max-\i)/(\max-4)}]
      (current page.north west) ++(\i mm,0)
      arc[start angle=0,end angle=-90,radius=\i mm];
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\wave
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another version with variable thickness:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\wave{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \fill[red,line width=.5mm,draw=red] (current page.north west) circle (3mm);
    \def\max{200}
    \foreach \i in {4,...,\max} {
      \pgfmathsetmacro\prop{(\max-\i)/(\max-4)}
      \draw[red,line width={.7mm*\prop},draw opacity=\prop]
      (current page.north west) ++(\i mm,0)
      arc[start angle=0,end angle=-90,radius=\i mm];
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\wave
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you do something with their thickness? Like they fade in colour, their thickness decrease...

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent: You can play around with the `line width`. Start with something like `line width=3.0mm/\i` and adjust this function as desired.

Comment: nice moiré effect :)

Answer (score 8):

Credits should go to Paul Gabroit because I didn't understand the question first. Thanks to him for the code too. Here is a variation of his answer.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\wave[1][north west]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \fill[red,line width=.5mm,draw=red] (current page.#1) circle (3mm);
    \def\max{20}
    \foreach \i in {4,...,\max} {
      \draw[red!\i!green,line width=12/\i mm,draw opacity={(\max-\i)/(\max-4)}]
      (current page.#1) circle (\i mm);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\wave
\wave[north east]
\wave[south west]
\wave[south east]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why cannot I put \max{200}?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent Use `red` (or any single color) instead of `red!\i!green` if you want `\max{200}`. It will take color out of bounds.

Answer (score 6):

I took a different approach and added fading to the expanding wave decoration:

[image: fading wave]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{fading waves}{initial}
{
  \state{initial}[width=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,next state=wave]
  {\gdef\opacity{1}}

  \state{wave}[switch if less than=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength to last,
               width=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{
      \pgfpointadd
      {\pgfqpoint{-\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance}{0pt}}%
      {\pgfpointpolar{\pgfdecorationsegmentangle}{+\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance}}}%
    \pgfpatharc{\pgfdecorationsegmentangle}{-\pgfdecorationsegmentangle}{+\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance}%
    \pgfsetstrokeopacity{\opacity}%
    \pgfusepath{stroke}%
    \pgfmathmultiply{0.7}{\opacity}% adjustable fade rate
    \global\edef\opacity{\pgfmathresult}%
  }
  \state{last}[width=+0pt,next state=final]
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{
      \pgfpointadd
      {\pgfqpoint{-\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance}{0pt}}%
      {\pgfpointpolar{\pgfdecorationsegmentangle}{+\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance}}}%
    \pgfpatharc{\pgfdecorationsegmentangle}{-\pgfdecorationsegmentangle}{+\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance}%
    \pgfsetstrokeopacity{\opacity}%
    \pgfusepath{stroke}%
  }
  \state{final}
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shape=circle,very thick,level distance=13mm,cap=round]
\draw[decorate,decoration={fading waves,angle=45}] (0,0) -- (1,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```